# Find substring inside parentheses and single quotes

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to get the string that is within the parentheses and within the `''`.

```
import re
a_string = "_TableStyle('Table Grid') id: 219287880"
result = re.findall(r'\((.*?) *\)', a_string)[0][1:-1]
print(result)
```

This block works. But isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: What does elegant qualify as?

Comment: What do you mean by more elegant way? Get the value between parenthesis or get the first value of the list?

Comment: [`\('(.+?)'\)`](https://regex101.com/r/KwfWyK/1) `re.search(r"\('(.+?)'\)", a_string).group(1)`

Comment: Why did you not include the single quotes in the regex?

Comment: If there is only one instance of (' and ') inside the string then you can split the string them as delimiter and fetch the middle element

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My own code wasn't very robust and sensitive for mistakes if there are more parentheses present. I tried to include the single quotes inside the regex, but I'm not that advanced in regex and I didn't get it to work. @Olvin Roght: Your solution was the one I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite inefficient to use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) for retrieving just first match, better to use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) which will return after first match found. Also you can simplify your regular expression to [`\('(.+?)'\)`](https://regex101.com/r/KwfWyK/1).

**Code:**

```py
import re
...
result = re.search(r"\('(.+?)'\)", a_string).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one pair of parentheses in your line, you can do it without regex:

```py
a_string = "_TableStyle('Table Grid') id: 219287880"

openParenthesis = a_string.index("('") + 2
closeParenthesis = a_string.index("')", openParenthesis)

# 'Table Grid'
a_string[openParenthesis:closeParenthesis]
```

Comment: But they want `Table Grid`, not `'Table Grid'`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, the code is the same, he just have to find index for `('`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's another way to achieve this. Here it is,

```
import re
a_string = "_TableStyle('Table Grid') id: 219287880"
result = re.findall(r'\(\'(.*?) *\'\)', a_string)[0]
print(result)
```

This code searches also for a ' ' and would only extract the text between the (' ').

**Edit:**

We can also write the code like this,

```
import re
a_string = "_TableStyle('Table Grid') id: 219287880"
result = re.search(r'\(\'(.*?) *\'\)', a_string).group(1)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes around the literal if you do not want to escape single quotes. Triple quotes are even nicer. Getting part of a regex match is simple with [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```py
import re
a_string = "_TableStyle('Table Grid') id: 219287880"
match = re.search(r"""\('([^']*)'\)""", a_string)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##NYxBDoIwFET3PcVPN/01hgguRBLXHkB3oqRCpU2ANp@64PS1aeKsZl7yxm/BuOUYo529owCkmerWQHYZ4QK8u6v3pG9hmzSK3OFKdhAS7NBAVZ6r@lTXB85mFXqTDNLFqhX1Bolz3qLAx0s8d1K0Mu09/M8lsx/IUsMgxScYMINiJPf1WEoZ4w8).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  '                        '\''
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```